# How does file system selection at hyperviser affect KVM VMs?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, filesystems, hypervisor

I'm new to hypervisors and will be setting up a single host machine with a hyperviser that supports multiple filesystem types (LVM, ZFS, NFS, Glustfs etcetera) - this hypervisor will then run a small number of KVM VMs. I'm a bit confused about the overall implications of choosing a particular file-system, which *might* also stem from my lack of understanding about KVM.

**Here is the scenario:**

I setup the host machine using ZFS.

I create a KVM VM instance to install software which doesn't support ZFS, and explicitly suggests XFS as the Filesystem.

What are the implications of this? Does it matter?

**My understanding so far**

My understanding so far is that this doesn't matter, and that filesystem passthrough is managed with VirtFS if it was ever needed but often isn't. But, i'd like to be sure, and I'd like an explanation for why it doesn't matter so I understand the system better.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KVM runs virtual machines. The disks of these virtual machines will be image-files on your ZFS. 
KVM will translate all disk accesses of your virtual machine's filesystems to accesses in the image-file on the ZFS on your host.

So if "randomly" changing large files on your ZFS is not an issue, it doesn't really matter what your virtual machine does with its disk.